# Pause on scrolling backgrounds

Tags: unity, parallax-scrolling

I have a typical parallax backgrounds. They are scrolling by

```
public float Speed=0f;

void Update () 
{
    renderer.material.mainTextureOffset = new Vector2 (Time.time*Speed,0);
}
```

I have a character. OnKeyDown he starts to move: Speed of background sets to 0.4f for example. OnKeyUp a character stops by setting the speed of background 0f. 
The problem is: when backgrounds stop to scroll, they return to its start position. They must just to pause the position. How to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [delta time](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) instead of total time. And keep the "running total" in your offset variable, instead of in time.

```
renderer.material.mainTextureOffset += new Vector2 (Time.detlaTime*Speed,0);
```

Then, when you come back from a pause, the `mainTextureOffset` is where you left it.